# Append image to bottom of div with padding

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I've looked at similar posts here, but can't seem to apply the concept correctly. I am wanting to append a small image to the bottom of a div to create a border effect on the div. I'm trying to use ::after, 'content' and relative positioning to the div, but it only get's me close. The div has a considerable amount of top/bottom padding. So when I try to add the image to the bottom of the div, it only adds it to the bottom of the div before the padding starts. I tried absolute positioning for the image and it ended up being at the bottom of the page and not the bottom of the div. Any ideas? Here is a reference for the page I'm working on. The image has been given a red background (halfway down the page for easy reference). http://www.staging.sarahandrachel.com/about/

Here is the markup for the div.

```
#block-4a4b3b44-9188-4b95-9678-d896851e0c54::after {
content: url('http://www.staging.sarahandrachel.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/08/header-bottom-frame.png');
position: relative;
bottom: 0px !important;
left: calc(50% - 40px);
z-index: 9999;
background: red;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Position: absolute;` is the right way to go about this. Make sure you've added `position: relative` to the `div` you are appending the pseudoelement to, in this case: `#block-4a4b3b44-9188-4b95-9678-d896851e0c54`

Comment: @ovokuro - does this still work using 'content' to display the image or does the image have to be actually coded inside the div as a child?

Comment: Added the image using `content` will work fine

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work. Been struggling with that for an unreasonable amount of time. Such a simple solution!